Plot an expression in which a variable satisfies an equation
My question is very simple. I have a function $f(r)$ with some other parameters and I want to plot ${f'(r)}/{4\pi}$ vs P where r is satisfying the equation $f(r)=0$. I don't know where am I doing wrong. I have tried the following code but gives no answer. Can any one help me?
f[r_]:=1 - (a*Q^4)/(20*r^6) + Q^2/r^2 - (2*M)/r + (8/3)*P*Pi*r^2 - c*r^(-1 - 3*\[Omega]
Clear[a, c, \[Omega], Q, M]
a = 0.5; 
c = 0.2; 
\[Omega] = -3^(-1); 
Q = 0.7; 
M = 10; 
rH = r /. Solve[f[r] == 0, r, Reals]
Plot[D[f[r], r]/(4*Pi) /. r -> rH, {P, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> {0, 10}, PlotStyle -> Green, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]


Replace the last line Plot's first argument with Last@DeleteCases[D[f[r], r]/(4*Pi) /. r -> rH, Undefined].

The revised code is another method subtlely different with the method posted in my answer and is closer to your thought.

code
f[r_, P_] = With[{a = 0.5, c = 0.2, \[Omega] = -3^(-1), Q = 0.7, M = 10},
    1 - (a*Q^4)/(20*r^6) + Q^2/r^2 -
    (2*M)/r + (8/3)*P*Pi*r^2 -
    c*r^(-1 - 3*\[Omega] )
];
g[r_, P_] = D[f[r, P], r]/(4*Pi);
Plot[
    g[Last@NSolveValues[f[r, P] == 0, r, Reals], P],
    {P, 0, 10},
    PlotStyle -> Green
]

explanation
Three parts:

f has macro slots(not local variables) named r and P, which corresponds with the third part explained next. (slot P is not necessary, as I find that P has local value in some Block, so this is just personal preference.) The body is as you defined.

g is defined with Set(=) rather than SetDelayed(:=), because we need the evaluated version of the latter body as it's definition's body.

Plot's first argument doesn't have Evaluate as outermost closure, because we need to utilize the HoldAll attribute to evaluate each solution for $f(r)=0$ with some given P dynamically. This method is more straightforward and fit with your need.


result


PS: This method is to first take some specific value for P, i.e. Symbol to Real, and then a numeric NSolve and yield a result sorted correctly, so we can just take the last one.

Use
 g[ P_] = D[f[r], r]/(4*Pi) /. r -> rH;

 g[0.1]
 {-238.689, 0.573223, Undefined, Undefined}

 Plot[ Evaluate[(g[P][[1 ;; 2]]/(4*Pi))] , {P, 0, 10}, 
  PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> {Green, Red}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]


